# Why button text-indent affect clickable area on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, text-indent

I have a  element where I utilize `text-indent: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden;` to conceal the text within it. This button is equipped with a click event. It functions smoothly on desktop computers, but when I test it on Google Chrome to simulate a mobile device, I encounter an issue with the button's clickable area.

Here is a demo:

https://codepen.io/zangbianxuegu/pen/MWLbWPZ

[image]

It appears that a specific area（A small area to the right） of the button is unresponsive to clicks. The second button will be more obvious.

Why does this happen?

The issue is resolved when I remove the text-indent or overflow: hidden styles. Alternatively, using a  element also eliminates this problem.

**Note that it is in mobile mode**